# How to set an alias to open a file in Bash

Tags: windows, bash, alias, command-prompt

I am trying to set an alias to open an Excel file from a directory on Windows 7.  Each time I use the alias it just opens a Windows Explorer window in the root directory.

I am entering:

```
alias openExcel="explorer /z/Company/AP/PR/thisExcelFile.xlsx"
```

I have also tried:

```
alias pr="cd /z/Company/AP/PR/"
```

Then:

```
alias openExcel="explorer thisExcelFile.xlsx"
```

Running these commands manually opens the Excel file.  But using the commands through an alias just opens Windows Explorer in the root directory.

I have also tried combining the bottom two commands in a function but that didn't work either.

Can alias' not be used to open files like this?  Is there some exception to how an alias works when you use the 'explorer' command on Windows?

Comment: Um, where exactly do you define these aliases (OS and shell)? I don't think it's WSL since you mentioned Windows 7. Could it be that you confused `cmd/batch` and `bash`?

Comment: What bash program are you using on Windows 7? Are you using gitbash or sygwin or something else? Does your `pr` alias work on it's own (changing the directory as expected)?

Answer (score 0):

Your commands are fine - you're just running the wrong application.

The first part is the command/executable, and the second is the argument. You just need to open the file with Excel.

```c
// This runs "Windows Explorer", with the parameter "thisExcelFile.xlsx"
explorer thisExcelFile.xlsx

// This runs "Microsoft Excel", with the parameter "thisExcelFile.xlsx"
excel thisExcelFile.xlsx
```

You can do the same with `winword myWordDoc.docx`, or `firefox www.google.com`.

It may also be a good idea to quote the argument, just in case:

```c
excel "thisExcelFile.xlsx"
```

Comment: Wow I didn't even know that was an option.  Thanks Addison!

To clarify to others, I'm using gitbash, sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @Haakasaurus - No worries mate. Accept the answer if it helped ya out.